# Django floppyforms setting PointField from (lat,lon) and vice versa

Tags: django, google-maps, django-floppyforms

Im trying to use floppyforms with some changes:

models.py:

```
class LocationPoint(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    radius = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
    point = models.PointField(srid=4326, null=False, blank=False)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

views.py:

```
def location_point_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LocationPointForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('ui:population-constraint-add')
    else:
        form = LocationPointForm()

    template = 'api/location_point_template.html'
    context = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
    return render_to_response(template, context)
```

forms.py:

```
class GMapPointWidget(floppyforms.gis.BaseGMapWidget, floppyforms.gis.PointWidget):
    google_maps_api_key = 'my-key'


class LocationPointForm(forms.ModelForm):
    latitude = forms.DecimalField(
        min_value=-90,
        max_value=90,
        required=True,
    )
    longitude = forms.DecimalField(
        min_value=-180,
        max_value=180,
        required=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = LocationPoint
        exclude = []
        widgets = {'point': GMapPointWidget(attrs={'map_width': 1000,
                                               'map_height': 500,
                                               'is_point': True,
                                               'mouse_position': True,
                                               'point_zoom': 1})}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LocationPointForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if args:  # If args exist
            data = args[0]
            if data['latitude'] and data['longitude']:  # If lat/lng exist
                latitude = float(data['latitude'])
                longitude = float(data['longitude'])
                data['point'] = Point(longitude, latitude)  # Set PointField
        try:
            coordinates = kwargs['instance'].point.tuple  # If PointField exists
            initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
            initial['latitude'] = coordinates[0]  # Set Latitude from coordinates
            initial['longitude'] = coordinates[1]  # Set Longitude from coordinates
            kwargs['initial'] = initial
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            pass
```

template.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
{{ form.media }}
<div class="container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Location Point</h1>
    </div>
    <form role="form" class="form-inline" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="dl-horizontal">
             <a href="{% url 'ui:population-constraint-add' %}">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Back</button>
             </a>
       </div>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       {{ form.as_p }}
       <div class="dl-horizontal">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
       </div>
       <br/>
       <br/>
   </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

I have three problems with this code:

1. The default zoom is way too close... the widget settings **point_zoom** in **GMapPointWidget** doesnt do anything.
2. As you can see in the screenshot above I trying to set the point to **Israel** with **lat,lon (31.0461, 34.8516)** but the point is placed in the ocean... why? Is there different lat lon calculation?
3. How can I do the other way around, I mean that I want to set a point on the map and see the lat,lon data in the boxes???

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help,
according to [floppyforms docs](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/geodjango.html)

1. in the html try set:

> ```
> {% block options %}
>     options['point_zoom'] = 9;
>     options['default_zoom'] = 2;
> {% endblock %}
> ```

2. you can try change the Widget attribute: 'map_srid' to 900913 (google like lat lon)
   the default is 4326
   it should look somthing like this:

> ```
> class GMapPointWidget(floppyforms.gis.BaseGMapWidget, floppyforms.gis.PointWidget):
>     map_srid = 900913  # Use the google projection
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You car rewrite with use of

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import PointField
p = Point(
        85.3240, 
        27.7172,
        geography=True, 
        # srid=4326 - default_value
)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield